# getElementById does not post when name field is present in the file input

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

I'm writing a code to browse and upload a file in a single step. 
I have this code in place:

```
<input type="file" id="image" style="display: none;">
<input type="submit" name="upload" id="upload" value="upload"
  onclick="document.getElementById('image').click();">
```

This code allows me to select the file and also submit the form but I want to use the $_FILE attributes and since there is no name field in the file-input, I cannot access the file information.

So I modified my code to add the name field as follows

```
<input type="file" name="image" id="image" style="display: none;" />

<input type="submit" name="upload" id="upload" value="upload"
  onclick="document.getElementById('image').click();" />
```

Now, with this code, i'm still able to browse the file but it is not submitted. So in a nutshell i'm not able to access $_FILE with both the methods.

Any suggestion what I can do to move ahead. ??

TIA

Comment: Since you've posted no code whatsoever, we can't help you.

Comment: updated my question with the code.

Comment: You don't wanna redirect the page ?

Comment: No. I'm trying to upload images like in flicker etc. so I want to browse and upload the image at the same time. I have my PHP code in the same file which handles it to upload and preview. The code works well if I do it seperataly i.e file input and submit but I want to do this in single step.

Answer (score 1):

To have the selected image made available in the $_FILES array in PHP, you need to give the file field a name attribute and set the `enctype` of the form to `multipart/form-data` so that the browser posts correctly.

```
<form action="some.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" id="image" name="image">
 <input type="button" value="select image" id="button">
</form>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

To be able to still use the `.click()` method on the file input it must not have been taken out of the document (ie: `display: none` won't work), so you can use:

```
​input[type=file] {
 position: absolute; height: 0; width: 0; /* should be totally squashed */
 visibility: hidden; /* just in case */
}​
```

Then you can use your JavaScript to open the select dialog and submit the form

```
$('#button').click(function() {
  $('#image')[0].click();
});​​​​
$('#image').change(function() {
  $('form').submit();
});
```

​
(Here assuming that you have jQuery on your page, here's a working example http://jsfiddle.net/steveukx/V4yE3/)

Comment: enctype has caught me out on a couple of occasions!

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not supporting your method here (its does not separate markup from behavior), you could try adding a `return true` in `onclick`.

Answer (score 0):

This code just wont work cross-browser. On chrome, you can't call `click()` on a hidden `input[type=file]` element.

Even when you switch it to visible, putting the `click()` in an `onclick` or `onsubmit` handler will also not work - the form will not be submitted with the new file value. This is a security feature. Browsers do not want you to do this.

Flash can do what you want. Check out the YUI Uploader component: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/uploader/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload a file without reloading the page use [AJAX file upload jQuery plugin](https://github.com/jfeldstein/jQuery.AjaxFileUpload.js) uploads the file somehwere, and passes the response to a callback, nothing else.

```
It does not depend on specific HTML, just give it a <input type="file">
It does not require your server to respond in any particular way
It does not matter how many files you use, or where they are on the page
```

-- Use as little as --

```
$('#one-specific-file').ajaxfileupload({
  'action': '/upload.php'
});
```

-- or as much as --

```
$('input[type="file"]').ajaxfileupload({
  'action': '/upload.php',
  'params': {
    'extra': 'info'
  },
  'onComplete': function(response) {
    console.log('custom handler for file:');
    alert(JSON.stringify(response));
  },
  'onStart': function() {
    if(weWantedTo) return false; // cancels upload
  },
  'onCancel': function() {
    console.log('no file selected');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you just want to a) hide browser specific file browse control and provide your own styled button and b) select and upload file  at the same time (e.g. upload your photo when the file browse dialog is closed).
In this case you need something like that:

```
<form name="myForm" method="POST">
    <input type="file" name="image" id="image" 
        style="position: absolute; left: -1000px;"
        onchange="myForm.submit();" />
    <input type="button" name="upload" id="upload" value="upload"
        onclick="document.getElementById('image').click();" />
</form>
```

Works in Chrome (don't hide file input but move it outside the page). If there are any issues with other browsers I would recommend to use jQuery.
HTH

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="file" id="image" onchange="yourForm.submit();">
```